# Find an image with special src in html-collection

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I just would like to get an image within the html-collection of a page which contains "apple" in its `src` (for example - [www.domain.com/images/apple-desktop/..](http://www.domain.com/images/apple-desktop/..). ) and check if it exists and afterwards do something.

```
var allimg;
var ilist = document.images;
for (var i = 0; i < ilist.length; i++) {
   if(ilist[i].src.includes('apple')) {
       allimg = true;
   } else {
       allimg = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try converting the HTMLCollection to an Array using `Array.from()` method: `var ilist = Array.from(document.images)`

Comment: if your image after true is false again, you reset the var to false, you probably want to also break out of the loop once you get a true

Comment: You are not breaking the loop if you got one , it will keep running . You need to break the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `else` branch, as it will set the variable to false each time an image does not match. You can also break out of the loop once you find a matching source to be more efficient.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ilist.length; i++) {
   if(ilist[i].src.includes('apple')) {
       allimg = true;
       break;
   } 
}
```

Comment: but in case he has more than 1 link with the word apple you break all the loop, if he has more than 1 link with the word apple and he wants to change it as well? so than its not so good to break the loop. depend what he needs.

Comment: @Elnatan vazana You are misunderstanding the question. The asker wants to know if such an image exists, so a boolean is being used instead of an array. Setting the variable to true once or ten times has the same result, so breaking the first time the condition is true is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether there is an `img` containing a keyword in its `src` you could use either [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) combined with attribute selector.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=apple]').length
);

console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=orange]').length
);
```

```html
<img src = '/lala/apple/lala' />
<img src = '/lala/banana/lala' />
<img src = '/lala/apple/lala' />
```

Now to just check if there is any you can use `querySelector()` to retrieve the first matching element (or null) and turn the result into a boolean:

```
var allimg = !!document.querySelector('img[src*=apple]');
```

or stay with `querySelectorAll()` and use its `length`:

```
var allimg = !!document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=apple]').length;
```

To reuse matching elements you can combine `querySelectorAll()` with `forEach()`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=apple]').forEach(function(item){
  item.style.border = '10px solid red'
});
```

```html
<img src = '/lala/apple/lala' />
<img src = '/lala/banana/lala' />
<img src = '/lala/apple/lala' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allimg=false;
var appleImg ;
var ilist = document.images;
for (var i = 0; i < ilist.length; i++) {
   if(ilist[i].src.includes('apple')) {
       allimg = true;
       appleImg = ilist[i];
       break;
   } 
}
console.log(allimg);// will be false if there is no such img found
console.log(appleImg); // will be undefined it there is no image with apple as src
```

```html
<img src="apple.jpg" alt="flower" width="150" height="113">
<img src="klematis2.jpg" alt="flower" width="152" height="128">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote , who so ever downvoted ?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but the original version of the answer did not work.

Answer (score -1):

in case you have more than 1 link with apple and you want to loop through all the links and do something with them this should work.

```
var allimg;
var ilist = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < ilist.length; i++) {
   if(ilist[i].src.includes('apple')) {
       allimg = true;
     ilist[i].style.border = '1px solid red'
     //do something with the item
   } else {
       allimg = false;
   }
  console.log(allimg)
}
```

in this example the link with apple will get red border and all the rest not.

this is a working code pen for example
https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/WNwQjMq

Comment: this is exactly the same as what op posted. the only thing you changed was document.images, and that didn't add any value to the code whatsoever.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt matter if i use document.images or getElementsByTagName - it remains false. however i do find the image in the html-dom or array.

Comment: @DarvudPaci check the code pen please https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/WNwQjMq and tell me there is only one link with apple or more?

Comment: when i type in for example ilist[6].src in the console, it displays me the correct src i want to find. but the for loop doesnt seem to work